# What are the Pontryagin duals of additive and multiplicative group of complex number?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

What are the Pontryagin duals of additive and multiplicative group of complex number?

So basically what are all characters of $(\mathbb{C},+$) and $(\mathbb{C^*},.)$?

Answer (score 2):

For Pontryagin duality, the characters are the continuous homomorphisms to $S^1$, not to all of $\mathbb{C}^\ast$, as characters are defined in some other circumstances.

We have $\widehat{G\times H} = \widehat{G}\oplus \widehat{H}$, and it is probably known that $\widehat{\mathbb{R}} \cong \mathbb{R}$ and $\widehat{S^1} \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Writing $(\mathbb{C},+)$ and $(\mathbb{C}^\ast,\cdot)$ as products of simpler groups then gives the answer.

Comment: @Danilel what is meant by simpler groups?

Comment: Groups whose dual group is known. $(\mathbb{C},+) \cong (\mathbb{R},+)\times (\mathbb{R},+)$ should be easy to see, and for $(\mathbb{C}^\ast,\cdot)$, the other listed group should give an idea.